# eclipse throwing unnecessary errors

Tags: eclipse

While creating dynamic web project in Eclipse ide sometimes it throws some unexpected errors like resource not found etc. Restarting eclipse several times solves the problem. Can any one please tell whats the reason for this and how to make working of eclipse more stable.

Answer (score 0):

To make Eclipse more stable, apply the lastest fixes.   EclipseMenu -> Help -> CheckForUpdates

Comment: I am already using the latest version. I have also used NetBeans, but it looks more promising than Eclips in terms of throwing unnecessary errors.